# stylesheet drawing a line under the table data

Tags: html, css

I am using **CSS** and **HTML** to create a table  and before the last row there is a horizontal line. The horizontal line is not on table row but it's on table data.

```css
#FormatTable {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 13px;
}
table {
  border: 13px solid #33FFFF;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 6px 14px;
}
tr.headerrow {
  font-weight: bold;
}
td.tac {
  text-align: center;
}
tr.aaa {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000000;
}
tr.alt2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="FormatTable">
  <table>
    <tr class="headerrow">
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Manufacturer</td>
      <td>Size</td>
      <td class="tac">Unit Price</td>
      <td class="tac">Quantity</td>
      <td class="tac">Total Price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowcee">
      <td>Corn Flakes</td>
      <td>Kellog's</td>
      <td>18 oz.</td>
      <td class="tac">2.50</td>
      <td class="tac">1</td>
      <td class="tac">2.50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowdf">
      <td>Solid White tuna</td>
      <td>Starkist</td>
      <td>5 oz.</td>
      <td class="tac">2.79</td>
      <td class="tac">2</td>
      <td class="tac">5.58</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowcee">
      <td>Cream of mushroom Soup</td>
      <td>Campbell's</td>
      <td>10.75 oz.</td>
      <td class="tac">1.00</td>
      <td class="tac">2</td>
      <td class="tac">2.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowdf">
      <td>2% Low Fat Milk</td>
      <td>Safeway</td>
      <td>0.5 gal</td>
      <td class="tac">1.99</td>
      <td class="tac">1</td>
      <td class="tac">1.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="aaa">
      <td>Extra-Wide Egg Noodles</td>
      <td>Golden Grain</td>
      <td>12 oz.</td>
      <td class="tac">0.87</td>
      <td class="tac">3</td>
      <td class="tac">2.61</td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="alt2">
      <td>Total</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="tac">9</td>
      <td class="tac">14.68</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: and the issue is...?

Comment: the Issue is that the line I am drawing is basically the border-bottom of the row before the last row. This draws the complete line over the last row. I don't want to do this I want to draw a line over the data (Line should start from Extra Wide- Noodles and End on 2.61)

Comment: Lke this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dpmf3szw/?

Comment: Also the issue is that i can't add the screenshot as an image here If i do i will show you exactly how

Comment: Update your question with a link to the screenshot and someone with enough rep can embed it.

Comment: http://tinypic.com?ref=o9luvm

Comment: No Its Text Decoration. If you look closely the thing is that the bottom-border which i am drawing is starting from the table border (of silver colour) but i want that line should start just under the text. Like line should start under the Egg Noodles.

Comment: I don't get the image form the link . is image link working correctly?

Comment: http://i61.tinypic.com/2csjm2x.jpg

Comment: @j08691 Can You check it now

Comment: @Jigs please check the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#FormatTable {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 13px;
}
table {
  border: 13px solid #33FFFF;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing:0px;
  padding:15px;
}
td {
  padding: 6px 14px;
}
tr.headerrow {
  font-weight: bold;
}
td.tac {
  text-align: center;
}
   

 tr.aaa td{
      border-bottom: 5px solid #000000;
    }
tr.alt2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="FormatTable">
  <table>
    <tr class="headerrow">
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Manufacturer</td>
      <td>Size</td>
      <td class="tac">Unit Price</td>
      <td class="tac">Quantity</td>
      <td class="tac">Total Price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowcee">
      <td>Corn Flakes</td>
      <td>Kellog's</td>
      <td>18 oz.</td>
      <td class="tac">2.50</td>
      <td class="tac">1</td>
      <td class="tac">2.50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowdf">
      <td>Solid White tuna</td>
      <td>Starkist</td>
      <td>5 oz.</td>
      <td class="tac">2.79</td>
      <td class="tac">2</td>
      <td class="tac">5.58</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowcee">
      <td>Cream of mushroom Soup</td>
      <td>Campbell's</td>
      <td>10.75 oz.</td>
      <td class="tac">1.00</td>
      <td class="tac">2</td>
      <td class="tac">2.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowdf">
      <td>2% Low Fat Milk</td>
      <td>Safeway</td>
      <td>0.5 gal</td>
      <td class="tac">1.99</td>
      <td class="tac">1</td>
      <td class="tac">1.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="aaa">
      <td>Extra-Wide Egg Noodles</td>
      <td>Golden Grain</td>
      <td>12 oz.</td>
      <td class="tac">0.87</td>
      <td class="tac">3</td>
      <td class="tac">2.61</td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="alt2">
      <td>Total</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="tac">9</td>
      <td class="tac">14.68</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh Thanks a lot please everyone i am sorry if i wasn't that much clear but this is exactly how i want this ! Thanks @MayurG

Comment: welcome...got first points from you :)

Comment: if u got ur answer can i get green tick to my answer...as i am new to this site :)

Comment: I am also new thanks man will surely ask you again in case of any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your td padding is making the row wider than the data in it. Try

```
td:first-child {
  padding: 6px 14px 6px 0px;
}
td:last-child {
  padding: 6px 0px 6px 14px;
}
```

**(Edit)** To pad between the table and the border, you need to put the border around the div, not the table.

```
#FormatTable { 
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 13px;

  padding: 30px;
  border: 13px solid #33FFFF;
  width: -webkit-min-content; 
  width: -moz-min-content;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

The width specifiers tell the div to only be as wide as the content, not the full screen. You may also want to tell the cell text not to wrap:

```
td {
  padding: 6px 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you but the thing is i want some padding and row wider but the line shoudn't touch the outside border

Comment: http://i61.tinypic.com/2csjm2x.jpg

Comment: Just like in the link

Comment: Yeah, never mind - the first answer is better.  :)